# Cant assign values to an unsigned char*

Tags: c++, char

kind of new to c++ but im having issues running this code. It crashes after I tried to assign the first element to a char.

```
int main() {
    unsigned char *data;
    int dataLength = 4;
    data[0] = 't'; // crashes
    data[1] = 'e';
    data[2] = 's';
    data[3] = 't';
    
    cout << myFunction(data, dataLength);
    cin.get(); 
}
```

Might anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: You have an uninitialized pointer.  It's supposed to point at a memory location that has been reserved for use by your program.  Right now, it's pointing to no defined location, and you have undefined behavior.  Why don't you just make it an array instead: `unsigned char data[] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };`

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `data`. Before you can use the pointer, you first need to make it actually point to something.

Comment: @paddy oh jeez man I feel like an idiot. myFunction requires the datatype to be an unsigned char and my compiler was throwing me errors saying : a value of type "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "unsigned char *. Though using your way it works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to read some introductory material about the language so you don't end up guessing your way through it.  Maybe start with Stroustrup's list of learning resources: https://stroustrup.com/C++.html#learning

Comment: @paddy Appreciate the link. Im pretty unfamiliar with c++ and mostly do web development. Its for a particular type of cryptography and I figure ill break down the questions bit by bit.